# I have a table friends , fields are(id, user1, user2, datamade, accepted (0,1)). login_user is either user1 or user2.

Tags: php

I have a table in the database friends , fields are (id, user1, user2, datamade, accepted (0,1)). login user is either user1 or user2. If user1 is login user, user2 is a friend and oposite. I want to echo something that only his friends can see.. What I want to echo is info from another table in the database tables name is posts(id, body, date_added, added_by, user_posted_to, image).

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM posts";
$query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $post_id = $row["id"];
    $body = $row["body"];
    $date_added = $row["date_added"];
    $added_by = $row["added_by"];
$image = $row["image"]; 
 $all_friends = array();
$sql = "SELECT user1 FROM friends WHERE user2='$log_username' AND accepted='1' ORDER BY RAND() ";
$query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    array_push($all_friends, $row["user1"]);
    $fr = $row["user1"];
    echo $fr;}
$sql = "SELECT user2 FROM friends WHERE user1='$log_username' AND accepted='1' ORDER BY RAND() ";
$query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    array_push($all_friends, $row["user2"]);
    $fr2 = $row["user2"];
echo $fr2;}
if ($added_by == $fr or $added_by == $fr2){
    echo "<div></div>";}}
```

Comment: Do you have a specific problem? Are you getting any error?

Comment: Yes it does not output the posts of all the friends in the array. Only one post!